# Apache Axis2 rahas-1.6.2.mar toSAXParseException when Axis2 is deploying rahas

Tags: apache-axis

I amy writing an `Apache Axis2` client to call some remote web services.
I can get it to work but I also need to deploy the rahas model because the remote server is using security.  When I add `rahas-1.6.2.mar` to my `$Axis_Home/repository/module` I get the exception below.  If I remove it then I do not get the exception. 
Does anyone know how to fix this?

> 2012/11/29 20:45:43:567 GMT [ERROR] XMLConfigurator - Configuration
>   file does not validate against schema org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: UndeclaredPrefix:
>   Cannot resolve 'xt:DEFAULT' as a QName: the prefix 'xt' is not
>   declared.     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.Util.toSAXParseException(Util.java:109)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ErrorHandlerAdaptor.error(ErrorHandlerAdaptor.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:382)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:316)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:429)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3185)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processOneAttribute(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2799)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2735)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2094)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:335)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.startElement(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1072)
>     at
>   org.apache.xml.serializer.TreeWalker.startNode(TreeWalker.java:357)
>     at org.apache.xml.serializer.TreeWalker.traverse(TreeWalker.java:143)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.process(ValidatorImpl.java:220)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:141)
>     at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:82)   at
>   org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.validateConfiguration(XMLConfigurator.java:373)
>     at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:162)
>     at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:142)
>     at
>   org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.rahas.RampartSAMLBootstrap.bootstrap(RampartSAMLBootstrap.java:79)
>     at org.apache.rahas.Rahas.init(Rahas.java:41)   at
>   org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.initModules(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.init(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)